# django how to refresh the html template after hard reload in django

Tags: django-templates, conditional-statements

I am trying to show the form output on the same page after the submission and hide it if I hard reload the page. So far, I have linked the condition to the message.success: if I submit the form, I see the output on the page. However, if I reload the page, I still see the output so I assume the message.success was not a smart solution for the condition. How can I add the condition to make the output appear on the page after the form submission and disappear after the reload? If there is a pure django solution, that would be great! Thank you!

```
def index(request):
    form = PlayersForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'success')
            return redirect('/')
    our_players = TriviaSet.players_objects.all().values().order_by('-id')[:1]
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form, 'our_players': our_players})
```

```
      {% if messages %}

        <ol style="margin-top: 30px; display: block" >
          {% for player in our_players %}

          <li style="margin: 5px 0 5px -50px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 10px; list-style: none;">
            {{player.player_name1|capfirst}} and {{player.player_name2|capfirst}}, <br> let's
            start the game!</li>

          {% endfor %}
        </ol>

      {% endif %}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'reload'? The reload button on the browser will always send exactly the request you sent the last time. So reload button after post-request, will issue a new post-request and therefore invoke the same behavior as before. You could add something like "player already exist", or some other checks that do not allow the second post-request issued by reload.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to code a simple game, the names of the players should appear on the page while they are playing and disappear if the user reloads or closes and reopens the window. Basically it should restart the game. I also want to store all players names and scores so that the names and scores appear at the end of the game session, comparing the current players to all previous players.